# what am I missing in my button to move to another screen?

Tags: java

Ok so as I am new to this work i just followed a youtube video exactly and it has not worked. I thinks it might be indicating to create a variable?

```
         button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
            openactivity_machine();
        }
         });
        public void openactivity_machine() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,openactivity_machine);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: We have no idea what you are trying to do or what the plan is... You could be building a UI for a webserver, you could be creatibg a game engine, all I can see that you're using Java... Please specity what you are trying to do, what you've already done and what exactly you're stuck on on the way to get to your goal.

Comment: I am creating an app that just has two list views and im saving the selections to a server database, so i need a button to go from one  screen to another and im getting errors with my openactivity_machine.

Comment: Shall we guess what error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not know about your **openactivity_machine** variable but switching activity should be this

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivityName.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```